# ThreadPoolExecutor really only executing amount if tasks given?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor, blockingqueue

In my Main Class I'm calling the Runnable Class Browser multiple times with an URL using blockingQueue.offer(..), which is linked to my

```
ThreadPoolExecutor pool =
                new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 10, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                        blockingQueue, new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy());
```

To see if it's working as desired, I'm caling a loop with

```
System.out.println("Currently executing threads: "+ pool.getActiveCount());
```

and I am getting 5 in most cases (except at the beginning when not 5 threads have started yet, which is also fine).

The browser class also has a notification at the beginning, for me to see which URL has been now used. What really grinds my gears is, when I execute the code, I get a notification from all browsers with their URLS, around 60.

My question is, is the ThreadPoolExecutor initiating every task/thread and then putting on hold or freezing? Because I would rather expect 5 browsers notifying their start until one finishes and a new one starts. Is my expectation wrong?

Browser Class:

```
public class Browser implements Runnable {

public Browser(URL webPage, ArrayList<String> proxyListMain, ArrayList<String> proxyListDetail, String division)
            throws IOException {
        this.webPage = webPage;
        this.proxyListMain = proxyListMain;
        this.proxyListDetail = proxyListDetail;
        this.division = division;
        System.out.println("Browser: " + webPage);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {...}
...}
```

Comment: Browser class? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I have now added minimal example to Browser class. The notification is in the constructor and gets called for all my URLs, instead of the 5 that should be running. Dont get it!

Comment: Of course it will show for all created. It is a runnable which you execute later with your pool. Only the `run` method is called from the threads in the pool **not** the constructor.

Comment: Just learned something new. I put the notification inside the run method and now it's behaving as expected. Thanks! @M.Deinum